# How to change color with using anychart-core js?

Tags: javascript, colors, marker, anychart

I have created a dynamic chart using any-chart core js library  link `https://docs.anychart.com/`

The code is

```
var chart = anychart.radar();
      // set chart yScale settings
      chart.yScale()
        .minimum(0)
        .maximum(10)
        .ticks({'interval':2});

       chart.yGrid().stroke({
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)",
          thickness: 1,
          opacity: 1,
        });
       chart.xGrid().stroke({
         color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)",
         thickness: 1,
         opacity: 1
       });

      // create first series
      chart.line(data1);
                  
      // set chart title
      chart.title("");

      // set container id for the chart
      chart.container('spider_graph');
      // initiate chart drawing
      chart.draw();

       // set data and adjust visualisation
      var series = chart.line(data1);

      // enable markers on series
      series.markers(true);
```

it will add marker also like

[image]

so the pointers are conneceted with line i want to change that color red to anything else.

If i didn't create marker the color is applied using chart.palette(["Yellow"]); but i want both marker with diffrent color line.

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

To have different line and markers colors, you’ll need to use fill() method for the markers(), and as you correctly mentioned palette() method for the line color.

```
// change color for the line
chart.palette(["Blue"]);
  
// change color of the markers
series.markers().fill("red");
```

Shown in sample here: https://playground.anychart.com/oEm8K8hK/4